# Isolating one number from a string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In my view I have

```
<%= version.object_changes %>
```

Here is an example of it's output

> --- !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess\nmanufacturer_id:\n-
>   \n- 2\nminiature_id:\n- \n- 37\ncreated_at:\n- \n- 2014-05-13
>   15:50:08.685560000 Z\nupdated_at:\n- \n- 2014-05-13 15:50:08.685560000
>   Z\nid:\n- \n- 59\n

I want to isolate the manufacturer_id and use it to display the manufacturer name.

```
<%= Manufacturer.find(xxxxx).name %>
```

I could isolate the manufacturer_id if it was a hash but it's just a text string.

I guess I want a way of saying find the line "manufacturer_id: - - x" and take "x". Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't mention it in your question, but I think you are using [`paper_trail`](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail) gem in your code.

`version.object_changes` stores the data in text form in database, so, you can't extract id from that like this. But you can use `version.changeset` to get the changes in hash.

Read more about it on their [documentation here](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail#diffing-versions).

> The best way to diff adjacent versions is to get PaperTrail to do it for you. If you add an object_changes text column to your versions table, either at installation time with the rails generate paper_trail:install --with-changes option or manually, PaperTrail will store the changes diff (excluding any attributes PaperTrail is ignoring) in each update version. You can use the version.changeset method to retrieve it.

**EDIT**: Based on the comment by OP below and update in answer, I will suggest extraction with regexp like:

```
if exp = version.object_changes.match(/manufacturer_id:\n- \n- (\d+)/)
  exp[1]
end
=> "9"
```

Comment: I didn't mention it because in this case I am working outside of paper_trail's normal behaviour. I've made a Version model and am accessing versions in a way that means version.changeset doesn't work. It's all a result of trying to work around paper_trail's inability to work fully with has_many through relationships.

Comment: Updated answer. Plausible way to do that for now is with regular expression extraction, in my opinion.

Comment: Looks great but I can't get that to work at all. In the model or the view or the console.

Comment: I wrote that method considering version.object_changes as string with the value in your question above. Works just fine for me. You may need to give more input or work around it :)

Comment: How would you put it in a view? Every way I've tried has not worked and in the console it gives nil.

Comment: Err. First make sure that `version.object_changes` does indeed return that type of string value as you posted. If it does, I see no reason for it to not capture the value. Check the output of `version.object_changes.match(/manufacturer_id: - - (\d+)/)`. 
For inserting in view, that is your controller-side logic. If value is extracted, instantiate it as `@manufacturer = Manufacturer.find...` and use it in corresponding view.

Comment: Sorry, I'm inexperienced in this area. I've updated the example of object_changes in my question because this is still returning nil. I was quoting the output of object_changes in the view rather than the console. Slightly different. Probably the source of the problem?

Comment: I've got it. Replaced " - - " with "\n- \n-" and it works. Thank you so so much. Really helped me out. Thanks for being patient with a new coder.

Comment: I'm very glad that it helped you :). Keep up the good work; we are all here to learn.